# How can i download laravel 4 without composer?

Tags: download, laravel

I want to download laravel4 archive without using composer?
For example, on symphony site, we have two ways to download framework)

Comment: I guess the real question is "why" ? You'll be fighting an uphill battle if you're not willing to conform to the recommended approach of downloading, configuring and installing L4.

Comment: Yes, but composer has a few issues by itself... I think that was a really-really bad call the Laravel team made!

Answer (score 5):

There are a few zips floating around on the [laravel forums](http://forums.laravel.io/viewtopic.php?id=9173)

Having said that I don't know how up to date they'll be kept... Composer does take few minutes to get your head around, but it is well worth it

Answer (score 3):

You can download via [LaraPack](http://fian.my.id/larapack). It provide you ready-to-use Laravel instalation, so you don't have install it with Composer. It also gets weekly update.

Disclaimer: I'm creator of LaraPack.

Answer (score 0):

Composer is quite slower than any dependency manager as compared to npm or gem hence laravel has given a separate link to get latest version of laravel and its dependency code in a zip file, thank you so much laravel, here is the link for it.
http://fian.my.id/larapack/